# Spring MVC access static files on file system or create file inside WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am developing a Spring MVC3 app and I have the following scenario:

1. generate a pdf file
2. save it in c:/temp/something.pdf (I do that because I don't know how to save it inside the project, I get java.io.FileNotFoundException)
3. spring doesn't let me access static files outside my /resources folder :(

I have tried 2 options and failed at both of them:
a. generate the file inside the project
b. give access to static files on the file system.

Can you please help me?

Best regards.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Spring problem. Why don't you configure Apache/Tomcat etc to access that path via HTTP?

Comment: Because I don't really know how to do that. I was hoping that something like <mvc:resources mapping="c:temp/**" location="c:temp/" /> would do the trick but, it doesn't. And I get a "permission denied" when I try to create the file "locally".